# Adding/Appending objects to a nested JSON array via jq in a bash script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, append, jq

This is a followup to my previous post.

I've been able to dynamically add and append objects on a single JSON array.
However, I'm having difficulty when attempting the same on a nested array list.

Able to do this via sponge:

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Paul",
      "car": "Nissan",
      "colour": "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```

Append:

```
Enter name:
Joe
Enter Car Model:
BMW
Enter Colour:
Blue

Add a new entry? (y/n):  y
Enter name:  
Paul
Enter Car Model:  
Nissan
Enter Colour:  
Black

Add a new entry? (y/n):  n

{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Blue"
    },
    {
      "name": "Paul",
      "car": "Nissan",
      "colour": "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am attempting to do is something like this:

```
{
  "key1": "One",
  "key2": "Two",
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Black"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sarah",
      "car": "Mercedes",
      "colour": "Red"
    }
  ],
  "key3": "Three",
  "list2": [
    "list2"
  ],
  "key4": "Four",
  "list3": [
    {
      "key5": "Five"
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically want to add/append objects to the nested **profiles** array.

Been utilising the following after my Q&A and Loop:

```
jq --arg name "$name" --arg car "$car" --arg colour "$colour" ' .profiles += [{ $name, $car, $colour}] ' profiles.json | sponge profiles.json
```

And then reading the output to a variable to be used in my final jq command:

```
profiles=`cat profiles.json`
```

However, this final jq does not output correctly.

```
jq -n --arg key1 "$key1" --arg key1 "$key2" --arg profiles "$profiles" --arg key3 "$key3" --arg key4 "key4" --arg key5 "key5" '{$key1, $key2, "profiles": $profiles, $key3, "list2": ["list2"], $key4, "list3": [{$key5}]}' > new_model.json
```

Even if I change to:

```
"profiles": [.profiles],
```

Which gives null:

```
{
  "key1": "One",
  "key2": "Two",
  "profiles": [
    null
  ],
  "key3": "Three",
  "list2": [
    "list2"
  ],
  "key4": "Four",
  "list3": [
    {
      "key5": Five
    }
  ]
}
```

Considering the other key* values are being added dynamically and are not fixed; does anyone have any ideas on how I can add/append or input the profiles.json into the **nested** **profiles** array correctly?

Preferably excluding the start and end brackets {} of the profiles.json output.

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Black"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sarah",
      "car": "Mercedes",
      "colour": "Red"
    }
  ]
}
```

Possibly utilise jq and sponge (as done for the single array) after each Q&A block updating file as I go along, dropping the -n flag etc?
Slightly confused about the logic due to more moving parts and since the profiles array is nested within other key values which are being added dynamically as well.

Many Thanks

Comment: With all the processing you need, at one point it will be easier to write a short Python script and invoke it from bash...

Comment: This is true, although my aim is to fully script this in bash. Thanks

Comment: well, you already had to invoke `jq` which has its own "language" ... IIRC in most Linux distros jq usually needs to be installed, while Python is almost always available out of the box.

Comment: Thank you pepoluan. I was able to append and invoke a python script within my bash script as the last step. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there other keys does not invalidate the strategy you’ve used when there are no other keys.

As best I can tell, your problems start with using a bash variable to store the results:

```
profiles=`cat profiles.json`
```

This by itself of course is harmless enough (at least if the file is sufficiently small), but things go downhill from there.  For example, when you write:

```
 --arg profiles "$profiles"
```

the jq variable $profiles now holds a JSON string, which is not what you want. You could chase this rabbit down its rabbit hole by using `--argjson`, but to what end?

Comment: `--argjson` almost returns what I want. But I see what you mean; it returns an extra unwarranted `"profiles": {`

Comment: Got it to work! Thank you @peak, you pointed me in the right direction again.
Would you happen to know how to remove the quotes from certain output values under the same jq command?
Not for all, just integers ie. let's say `key5` is an integer `"5"`.
I attempted with `-r` but that did nothing.

Comment: To convert numeric strings to numbers, you can use `tonumber`.  You might find the following idiom useful: `(tonumber? // .)`

Comment: Thank you @peak. Had some trouble with it but eventually got it to output what I needed.